# Migrate from enterprise chef to open source chef

Tags: chef

I tested out Enterprise Chef and its 5 free nodes.  Since then, I have setup the open source chef and want to migrate three nodes from the enterprise setup to the open source server.  Aside from just changing the `chef_server_url` on each of my three nodes in the `client.rb` file, is there anything else I need to do to switch these nodes over successfully?  Or is there an easier way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Chef Server stores all the node and client data, cookbooks, and data bags, you have to move that data as well.

You can use [knife download /](http://docs.getchef.com/chef/knife.html#id149) and [upload](http://docs.getchef.com/chef/knife.html#id322) for that task (downloading from enterprise chef, changing URL, uploading to your chef server).

The [migration guide from Chef Server 10 to 11](http://www.getchef.com/blog/2013/03/12/5106/) follows pretty much the same principles. This might be helpful, too.

Comment: May I suggest the excellent knife-backup gem as well. It can backup all nodes,roles,cookbooks,etc. Locally. Link: https://github.com/mdxp/knife-backup